# My Android build succeeds locally but fails on Circle Ci

Tags: circleci

My Android build succeeds lo locally but fails on Circle Ci  with the following error log:

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForProductionRelease'.
>     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/61.jar --output /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/production/release/64.jar --input /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/45.jar --output /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/production/release/48.jar --input /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/43.jar --output /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/production/release/46.jar --input /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/80.jar --output /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/production/release/83.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/classes/production/release --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/productionRelease --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/tmp/kapt3/classes/productionRelease --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/0.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/1.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/2.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/3.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/4.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/5.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/6.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/7.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/8.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/9.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/10.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/11.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/12.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/13.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/14.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/15.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/16.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/17.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/18.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/19.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/20.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/21.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/22.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/23.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/24.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/25.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/26.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/27.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/28.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/29.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/30.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/31.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/32.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/33.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/34.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/35.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/36.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/37.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/38.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/39.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/40.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/41.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/42.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/43.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/44.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/45.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/46.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/47.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/48.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/49.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/50.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/51.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/52.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/53.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/54.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/55.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/56.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/57.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/58.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/59.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/60.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/61.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/62.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/63.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/64.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/65.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/66.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/67.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/68.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/69.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/70.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/71.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/72.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/73.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/74.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/75.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/76.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/77.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/78.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/79.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/80.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/81.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/82.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/83.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/84.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/85.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/86.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/87.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/88.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/89.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/90.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/91.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/92.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/93.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/94.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/95.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/96.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/97.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/98.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/99.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/100.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/101.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/102.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/103.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/104.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/105.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/106.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/107.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/108.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/109.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/110.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/111.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/112.jar --classpath_entry /home/circleci/workspace/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/production/release/113.jar --bootclasspath_entry /opt/android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar --bootclasspath_entry /opt/android/sdk/platforms/android-27/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar --min_sdk_version 16 --desugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes --legacy_jacoco_fix}

I would appreciate any help to tackling this.

Comment: Is the issue resolved at the end?

Comment: Urgh, i'm getting this error in the couple days. Have no clue what to do. @Po10cio any ideias?

Answer (score 0):

The error is pointing to all of the jar dependencies your project has, located at 'absolute' filepaths (e.g. /home/...).

This will be fine when running locally, however when ran in a container those dependencies should be encapsulated in your project directory (e.g. stored in a 'relative' filepath that will be uploaded in the container). This is because those jar files wont exist in that location in the container.

To fix, add the jar libraries to the app/libs directory in your project and retarget your references to the libraries.

Comment: Thanks, but i am lost, an example can help